# Bootstrap modal carousel - images and text overlapping and stacking on each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

It's supposed to show one image at a time with one caption at a time, but now I have one image on the top of the other one and the two captions overlapping each other at the bottom..

Any clues?

EDIT: I did include boostrap.js.

None of the css is editing this part of my html.

```
<!-- JQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

At the bottom of my html.

```
<!--Second column-->
<div class="col-md-6 modal-lg">
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <img src="media/mobile.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalmockupsmobile" class="img-circle" alt="Mockup">
    <h5><p>Mobile</p></h5>

    <div id="modalmockupsmobile" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Coming Soon!</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- Start Carousel -->
                <div id="mobilemockups_carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#mobilemockups_carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#mobilemockups_carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#mobilemockups_carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <li data-target="#mobilemockups_carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                </ol>

                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <p class="carousel-caption">Login Screen</p>
                        <img src="media/nq.jpg" alt="Login screen">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <p class="carousel-caption">Welcome Screen</p>          
                        <img src="media/union.JPG" alt="Welcome screen"> 
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mobilemockups_carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mobilemockups_carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Carousel -->

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--/.Second column-->
```

Comment: code works fine, you probably haven't linked to bootstrap.js

Comment: Hi. I did include bootstrap.min.js.

Comment: Anyone? It's still not working.